# Cooking up invariants of a group action

Tags: group-actions, invariant-theory

There are a lot of examples of a group action preserving a specific invariant. For example,

- $\mathrm{SL}(V)$ preserves volume element on $V$
- $\mathrm{SO}(V)$ preserves distance (or more generally, symmetric positive bilinear form) on $V$
- $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb{C})$ preserves cross ratio

and so on. My question is, is there any standard way to find these invariants when a specific group action is given?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by cross-ratios here for a general $V$ (do you mean some sort of Plucker coordinates type ratios?), but an obvious candidate is to start looking is the tensor invariants $[\mathcal{T}(V\oplus V^\vee)]^G=\bigoplus_{m,n}[V^{\otimes m}\otimes (V^\vee)^{\otimes n}]^G$.

Comment: @user10354138 Sorry for the confusion, I was thinking of $\mathrm{PGL}(2,\mathbb{C})$. I have edited the question.